# AngularJS filter "all" not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've a problem with my AngularJS Filter.
I don't understand why, but one of my select filter doesn't work well.
Here is the code of the select :

```
<select ng-model="filterUser" ng-options="user for user in userList" class="form-control">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

And the code of the list :

```
<tr ng-repeat="action in actions | filter:{user:filterUser, type:filterType, comment:filterComment}">
    <td>{{action.user}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

When the page is loaded, I have the correct list with the right users. If I select an user from the select list, I only have the actions from this user, but if I go back to "All", there's nothing more on the list.
But this list isn't destroyed as if I select again an user, I will then have his actions.

Any idea ? :)

Comment: can provide plunk with bug reproduce on it?

Comment: why not just have a function where when its selected it sets the filter to that user and then when you select all just have it set to null

Comment: Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7522/

But here it works. And I've put a $watch on my filterUser and when I'm on "All" the variable is set to null...

Comment: the only thing I can think of is there is something wrong with {user:filterUser, type:filterType, comment:filterComment}

can you update the jsfiddle with a more accurate build of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at your current set up with multiple filters I dont know what your data structure looks like but here is an example of how I would do it and maybe this will help.  here is the fiddle

```
        <select ng-model="currentUser" ng-options="user.name for user in users">
          <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

    <tr ng-repeat="action in actions | filter:currentUser.name">
      <td>
        {{action.name}}
      </td>
   </tr>
```

This data was just ripped from some crappy app i made but i kept your naming conventions.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {"id": 0, "name": "Abdominals"},
        {"id": 1, "name": "Abductors"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Adductors"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "Biceps"},
        {"id": 5, "name": "Calves"}
    ];
    $scope.actions = [
        {"id": 0, "muscle": "Abdominals", "name": "Crunch"},
        {"id": 1, "muscle": "Abductors", "name": "Plank"},
        {"id": 2, "muscle": "Adductors", "name": "Decline Crunch"},
        {"id": 4, "muscle": "Biceps", "name": "Curls"},
        {"id": 5, "muscle": "Calves", "name": "Jump Rope"}
    ];
}
```